# Enable scroll bar inside text box wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a comments textbox put inside a groupbox, which  occupies the whole bottom part of the screen.
I need to enable scroll bar both vertical and  horizontal when the text exeeds the current  size textbox .
But for me the textbox size is getting increased and scroll bar is enabled in the group box.

How shall i disable the scroll bar of the Group box and enable only the scroll bar inside textbox ?

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource FormWidthGridLength}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource FormColumnSpacerDouble}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!-- some controls here -->

  <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Header ="Comments">                  
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Comments}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />          
  </GroupBox>
```

Comment: What if you set the max height property on your TextBox?

Comment: But this will effect proportion of controls in the different resolution or screen size right?

Comment: It will only prevent the text box from growing beyond a certain height, it will  still be able to shrink for smaller form factors. You can also set this value relative to the size of other controls using `RelativeSource`.

Comment: What are your row definitions? Have you tried setting HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment on the TextBox to Stretch? It will always fill the groupbox, though, which you may not want.

Comment: Here is how my row defenition `<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>`   and the groupbox which i was mentioning will reside in the last row.

Comment: @ Kidiskidvogingogin I tired setting the relative source to the parent controls still the groupbox is growing :(

Comment: Add `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to your GroupBox

Comment: @Chris thanks for pointing the mistake .       my parent view control was under a scroll viewer ..